# How to Validate only the visible fields in ReduxForm

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a form in which certain fields are shown/hidden based upon the selection of the value of the other field. Is there any way I can validate only the Visible fields, as currently it Registers all the fields available on the page and generate errors even if they are not shown.

Comment: Can you post your code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

**Facts**

1. What i'm about to say happens in redux-form 7.4.2
2. When a field "disappears" from the form Redux-Form will dispatch the action `@@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD`.
3. When a field "appears" in the form Redux-Form will launch the `@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD`.

**Behaviour**

Imagine that the first time the form is rendered that field is not there, therefore the field will not appear in the `registeredFields`in your store.

```
registeredFields {
  someOtherField: {name: 'someOtherField', type : 'Field', count: 1} 
}
```

Now you do something that triggers the form to re-render, the field "appears", redux-form dispatches `@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD`. If you now look at the store you will find your field under `registerFields` like so:

```
registeredFields {
  someOtherField: {name: 'someOtherField', type : 'Field', count: 1}
  conditionalField: {name: 'conditionalField', type : 'Field, count: 1}
}
```

What happens if you do something (click a checkbox) that causes the field to "dissapear" from the form?

redux-form will dispatch `@@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD` and this is how your store will look afterwards:

```
registeredFields {
      someOtherField: {name: 'someOtherField', type : 'Field', count: 1}
      conditionalField: {name: 'conditionalField', type : 'Field, count: 0}
}
```

Notice that the only thing that changed is the `count`.

You could use that to figure out if the field is "visible" or not by connecting the `registeredFields` via `connect` to your form.

The weird thing is that when you dispatch the `UNREGISTER_FIELD` field action "manually" (redux-tools or from code with `dispatch`) the whole key gets removed from the store like so:

Before:

```
registeredFields {
  someOtherField: {name: 'someOtherField', type : 'Field', count: 1}
  conditionalField: {name: 'conditionalField', type : 'Field, count: 1}
}
```

After "manually" dispatching `UNREGISTER_FIELD`

```
 registeredFields {
      someOtherField: {name: 'someOtherField', type : 'Field', count: 1}
 }
```

I think that's a bug. I think it should have the same behaviour. I'm going to raise an issue on GitHub.